# Scrape live streaming video using Node.js

Tags: web-scraping, video-streaming, screen-scraping

We can get Content from web page using scraping techniques.

**But if site is streaming a screen recording, it is using web sockets. There is no video file to download. I want to capture video stream and save it as MP4 or something like that.**

So is there any way i can capture video streaming of another site.

Looking for some suggestions
Thanks

Comment: It would be best if you could connect to the streaming server and get the media data directly.

Answer (score -1):

Some options

1: If available get the url from source tag

2: If sockets are not using authentication then you can directly connect

3: Check for some download video or screen record option in Puppeteer